# Group list of dictionaries to list of list of dictionaries with same property value

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have list of dictionaries and every dictionary has property person_id

```
[{'person_id': 1, 'something..': 'else'}, {'person_id': 3, 'something..': 'else'}, {'person_id': 1, 'something..': 'else'}]
```

How to group all dictionaries with same 'person_id' into list and split previous list of distionaries to list of list of dictionaries (inner list contains only dictionaries with same 'person_id').

```
[[{'person_id': 1, 'something..': 'else'}, {'person_id': 1, 'something..': 'else'}], [{'person_id': 3, 'something..': 'else'}]]
```

I done this with simple iteration and checking is already list with those dictionaries but is there efficient way in Python ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your input isn't sorted by `person_id`, so use a [`collections.defaultdict()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) approach with a loop:

```
from collections import defaultdict

grouped = defaultdict(list)

for person in inputlist:
    grouped[person['person_id']].append(person)

grouped = grouped.values()
```

This sorts the input list into buckets, then places all the buckets back into an outer list. If you need the output to be sorted by id, you could use:

```
grouped = [grouped['pid'] for pid in sorted(grouped)]
```

If you need the original list in sorted order, or can *produce* it in sorted order, you can also use [`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to do your grouping:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

grouped = [list(g) for p, g in groupby(inputlist, key=itemgetter('person_id'))]
```

but this does require that `inputlist` is sorted first.

Comment: @flornquake: actually, they are sorted.

Comment: Not in the first line of code. (sorry, I deleted my first comment right before I saw your answer)

Comment: @flornquake: ick, I missed that one.

Comment: @flornquake: adjusted to give the `defaultdict` approach first in that case.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Is big change if I want to group by two keys: person_id and job_id ?

Comment: @PaolaJ.: no, just use a tuple key: `grouped[person['person_id'], person['job_id']] = ...`, or for the `groupby` approach, `key=itemgetter('person_id', 'job_id')`.